# TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-forms

im getting this type error in React js

im trying to build a form in react js but the react throwning erroe like typeerroe the fullName in undefined . can anyone please help me in this issue .advance thank you .

```
×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullName' of undefined
Form
C:/crayond/crayondclientside/src/Form.js:45
  42 | <TextField
  43 |     variant="outlined"
  44 |     label="Full Name"
> 45 |     value={values.fullName}
  46 |     onChange ={handleInputChange}
  47 |     name="fullName"
  48 | 
View compiled
```

this is the code

```
import { makeStyles, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import UseForm from './Useform';


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme =>({
    root: {
            '& .MuiFormControl-root': {
                       width:'50%',
                       margin:theme.spacing(1)
    }
}
}))
const initialvalues = {
    fullName:" ",
    // password:"",
    email:" ",
    // profession:""

}

export default function Form() {


const classes = useStyles();


const {
    values,
    setValues,
    handleInputChange 
} = UseForm(initialvalues);




    return (
        <form className={classes.root}>
            <Grid container>
<Grid item xs={6}>
<TextField
    variant="outlined"
    label="Full Name"
    value={values.fullName}
    onChange ={handleInputChange}
    name="fullName"

/>

<TextField
    variant="outlined"
    label="email"
    value={values.email}
    onChange ={handleInputChange}
    name="email"

/>


</Grid>

<Grid item xs={6}>

</Grid>

            </Grid>
        </form>
    )
}
```

this is the custom hook

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';

function UseForm(initialvalues) {

const [values, setValues] = useState(initialvalues);

const handleInputChange = e => {
    const {name, value} = e.target
    setValues({
        ...values,
        [name]:value
    })
}

return(
    values,
    setValues,
    handleInputChange 
)




}

export default UseForm
```

please anyone helpme in this issue i dont know y the react is throwing this error

Comment: Type issue. Make sure that the custom hook you created `UseForm` is returning valid typings to `values`.

Comment: @rahulpsd18 its working now

Comment: Did you fix the typings or used `any` to ignore it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ? operator to avoid this kind of errors in frontend :

```
  43 |     variant="outlined"
  44 |     label="Full Name"
> 45 |     value={values?.fullName}
  46 |     onChange ={handleInputChange}
  47 |     name="fullName"
```

Also, make sure they are initialized and properly populated from API call.
Using any is not solving the problem, don't do that because this will make your code buggy.